# How to get around an InputMisMatchException in java

Tags: java, double

I have a file that I put some numbers into but then I decided I wanted to label the numbers with a name for each one, like so:

```
A = 1 2 3
B = 3 4 5
C = 6 7 8
```

This caused an exception to be thrown. I want to know how I can workaround this so the scanner 'ignores' all but the numbers unless I tell it otherwise.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Also, I already know what is causing the exception. I am using next.Double(); to pick out the numbers in the file.

```
public static void readFile() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

    String fileName = "vectors.txt";


    // Reference the file using the the BufferedReader object
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));    

    //scanner to scan through file 
    Scanner token = new Scanner(input);

    double fileX = token.nextDouble();
    double fileY = token.nextDouble();
    double fileZ = token.nextDouble();

    vecA = new Vector3D(fileX,fileY,fileZ);

    fileX = token.nextDouble();
    fileY= token.nextDouble();
    fileZ = token.nextDouble();

    vecB = new Vector3D(fileX, fileY, fileZ);

    fileX = token.nextDouble();
    fileY= token.nextDouble();
    fileZ = token.nextDouble();

    //initialize vecC using double values from third line of file
    vecC = new Vector3D(fileX, fileY, fileZ);


    //close file 
    input.close();


}
```

Comment: Come on, if you see an exception, you should post the code and the full exception. You've been here a bit, so this should be second nature by now (but you're likely trying to read text as a number or visa versa).

Comment: `"Also, I already know what is causing the exception. I am using next.Double(); to pick out the numbers in the file."` -- then don't do this. Seriously, though post your offending code for the best help.

Comment: I want to be able to do it though, that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make the scanner ignore input automatically, but you can write code to skip input yourself until you see that a double is available:

```
while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    scanner.next();
}
double d = scanner.nextDouble();
```

If you need to put this code in multiple places, you can wrap it in a function:

```
private static double skipAndGetDouble(Scanner scanner) {
    while (scanner.hasNext() && !scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        scanner.next();
    }
    return scanner.hasNextDouble() ? scanner.nextDouble() : Double.NaN;
}
```

Comment: That worked. I needed to put a while loop before each mismatch would occur for it to do the job.

Comment: @Magpie Rather than copying the `while` loop into multiple places, you can wrap it in a function. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: thanks, only I am confused about the syntax on this line     return scanner.hasNextDouble() ? scanner.nextDouble() : Double.NaN;

Comment: @Magpie That's a conditional operator: if the expression before the question mark `?` is true, the part before the colon `:` is returned; otherwise, the part after the colon is returned (a "not a number" value).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be very fancy, and come up with an over-kill solution, try changing the scanner's delimiter.  Check out [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the text that makes sense for the data being scanned. So in your case, you have lines that repeat the basic type of information held -- meaning use a loop -- don't repeat code unnecessarily.  In pseudocode

```
create a Scanner object read the file, say called fileScanner
while still lines to be read (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
  read line with fileScanner using .nextLine()
  Create a new Scanner object, lineScanner to get tokens in line.
  Use lineScanner to get `next` String via `.next()` and store
  Use lineScanner to get `next` String via `.next()` (the `=`) and ignore
  Use lineScanner to get 3 doubles.
  close line scanner
  Store all info in object and place in ArrayList or some other collection
end while
close fileScanner
```